# Insert hash array into an element in another hash array

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am looking for a solution in how to implement a hash array (with keys & values), and insert it (push it) into another hash array, in an uninstantiated element; for example:

```
$variable1 = {

          0 => {
                          'Mathematics' => 82,
                          'Art' => 99,
                          'Literature' => 88
                        },
          1 => {
                         'Mathematics' => 97,
                         'Literature' => 67
                       }
        };


$variable2 = { 'Biology' => 47, 'Theology' => 87 };
```

...

Where the first variable1 index is iterated chronologically as a counter 0, 1, 2, 3 ... n

Therefore final variable1 should be...

```
$variable1 = {

          0 => {
                          'Mathematics' => 82,
                          'Art' => 99,
                          'Literature' => 88
                        },
          1 => {
                         'Mathematics' => 97,
                         'Literature' => 67
                       }

          2 => {
                         'Biology' => 47, 
                         'Theology' => 87

                       } 


        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a hash as the outer structure?  If it were an array, it would just be:

```
$variable1 = [
    {
        'Mathematics' => 82,
        'Art' => 99,
        'Literature' => 88
    },
    {
        'Mathematics' => 97,
        'Literature' => 67
    }
];

$variable2 = { 'Biology' => 47, 'Theology' => 87 };

push @$variable1, $variable2;
```

Or if you want to push a copy (so that changes to `$variable1->[2]` don't affect `$variable2`),

```
push @$variable1, { %$variable2 };
```

With the structure you have, you'd have to do something like:

```
# assuming numbers are always sequential and start at 0
$variable1->{ keys %$variable1 } = $variable2;

# or if not
my $max_index = List::Util::max( keys %$variable1 ) // -1;
$variable1->{ $max_index+1 } = $variable2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your keys are numeric, and you want to push new elements into structure, [`array of hashes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) is more natural to hold your data,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @variable1 = (
  {
    'Mathematics' => 82,
    'Art' => 99,
    'Literature' => 88
  },
  {
    'Mathematics' => 97,
    'Literature' => 67
  }
);


my $variable2 = { 'Biology' => 47, 'Theology' => 87 };

push @variable1, $variable2;

print Dumper \@variable1;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'Art' => 99,
        'Literature' => 88,
        'Mathematics' => 82
      },
      {
        'Literature' => 67,
        'Mathematics' => 97
      },
      {
        'Biology' => 47,
        'Theology' => 87
      }
    ];
```